# VBscript: Verifying that a file has been completely copied/error handling

Tags: error-handling, vbscript, copy, verify

I am trying to add something to my script that will let me know if a file that I am copying has been fully copied.

Basically I am zipping up a bunch of files and then sending them to a mapped drive on the network. Then I have my script deleting the files in the original location once they have been successfully copied over. The script works perfectly fine but I just need to add in some error handling that will let me know if the copy was not completed successfully.

I have never used any error handling in vbscript as I am only about a week into this so any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if I need to explain anything more in depth. My script can be found below:

---

```
Option Explicit


Dim sDirectoryPath, sDestinationPath, sOutputFilename, Shell, sFileExt, sFilePrefix

shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
```

'Specify Directory Path where files to be zipped are located
'Specify destination for zipped files
'Specify file extension name to look for
'Specify prefix of filename to look for

```
sDirectoryPath = "C:\Testscripts\"
sDestinationPath = "C:\Script\files\outzips\"
sOutputFilename = shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%COMPUTERNAME%")
sFileExt = ".evtx"
sFilePrefix = "Archive*"


Dim Command, RetVal
Dim d : d = Date() 
Dim dateStr : dateStr = Year(d) & "-" & Right("00" & Month(d), 2) & "-" & Right("00" &   Day(d), 2)
Dim t : t = Time()
Dim timeStr: timeStr = Hour(t) & "-" & Right("00" & Minute(t), 2) & "-" & Right("00" & Second(t), 2)



Command = """C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe"" a  " & sDestinationPath & sOutputFilename & "-" & dateStr & "-" & timeStr & ".zip " & sDirectoryPath & sFilePrefix & sFileExt


        RetVal = Shell.Run(Command,0,true)

Wscript.Sleep 2000



Dim objFso  

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

'Copy files from one path to another

```
objFSO.CopyFile "C:\script\files\outzips\*.zip" , "G:\CopyTestFolder\"

If err.Number <> 0 Then
WScript.Echo "An error occured copying this file, re-attempt copy"
Else
WScript.Echo "No errors occured, copy successful"
End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

'After files have been successfully zipped and copied specify where to delete
'old zip files from, and the local archived folder path to delete

```
objFSO.DeleteFolder("C:\Script")
```

'Can either delete entire archived folder, or just .zip files in folder

```
objFSO.DeleteFile("C:\Testscripts\Archive*.evtx")
```

'Location where original files are that need to be deleted after the copy is successful

Comment: Was my answer sufficient, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 't' command on 7-zip to verify integrity.  If '0' ok, else error.

For example:

```
Set myshell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim cmd, result
cmd = """C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe"" t C:\NOT_a__valid_zip_file.zip"
result = myshell.Run(cmd,0,true)
Wscript.Echo "Not a valid zip file:  " & result

cmd = """C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe"" t C:\a_valid_zip_file.zip"
result = myshell.Run(cmd,0,true)
Wscript.Echo "A valid zip file:  " & result
```

Output:

```
PS> cscript.exe .\7z.vbs
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Not a valid zip file:  2
A valid zip file:  0
```

Comment: Sorry, I will be getting back to the script tomorrow, have had to deal with some problems that arose at work. Thank you for your reply and will see how it works out tomorrow.

Comment: Could you possibly run me through the logic on this? Is this saying that if the first command is true (i.e. the file is named something that isn't valid) then it returns the wscript.echo "Not a valid zip file:" and if the second cmd is true then it returns the wscript.echo of "A valid zip file" im just a little lost on where it is doing the if here

Comment: Also is there anyway that I could test to see if this works? I may just be having a horrible morning here but I can't think of a way to get the script to run and copy something that would produce the error

Comment: The example just shows that you can differentiate between a "bad" file (i.e. integrity test returns "not 0") and a "good" file (i.e. integrity test returns "0").  You said that you wanted to be able to tell if the copy was completed successfully.  You can do that by running the integrity test ('7z.exe t <file>') on the copied file. If the copy was successfully completed (and the file was good to begin with), then the test will return '0', otherwise, you know there was a problem (either with the file, to begin with, or in the copying process).

Comment: As far as testing this, I simply used a text file (i.e. not a zip file) to demonstrate the negative case.  You could also create a zip file, then use a hex editor to munge it up.  However, I think that the simply testing with a non-zip file is sufficient.

Comment: So basically this is how I understand it. If I run an integrity test before the zip process is started I can have it return the "Not 0" or "0" bad/good as to whether the files that are being told to be zipped are good to go. Then once they have been zipped, and I run the copy command, I can run the test again to test the integrity of the copied files to make sure that they are in fact where I told them to be copied to.

Comment: Ah okay, thinking about it again here. The test can only be run on .zip files. So I would only be able to do this once I had actually gone through the zip process and check the integrity after I had copied the .zip over to the new location.

Comment: The integrity test is on the zip file, itself, not on the files that are going to be zipped.  So, instead, do this (1) zip files; (2) integrity test on local zip file; (3) copy zip file; (4) integrity test on remote zip file.

Comment: Another approach is that, depending on how you are doing your copying, you could use the copy mechanism, itself, for verification.  For example, both xcopy and robocopy will verify the file, post-copy and report errors.  In addition, these tools will also perform a "move", i.e. delete the local file, in addition to copying to a remote location.  That would save you from doing that in your script.

Comment: Yes, this makes more sense after having my second coffee of the day lol. I will make the necessary changes, thank you for your help with this.

Comment: Hmmm just read your next comment. That seems like a much easier way to do this. So, once I've zipped the files, I can just perform a robocopy on the file outputting to the mapped drive, and then if the file is not completely copied it will report an error? I thought about using the ability to move the file in vbscript but then if something happens along the way I do not have the origina.

Comment: This is the line I'm using to run robocopy. I am getting a statement error, I know I'm missing a paren somewhere. Could you take a look at it? Command2 = "C:\Windows\System32\Robocopy.exe " & C:\script\files\outzips\ & " " & G:\CopyTestFolder\

Comment: You could also do both.  IOW - you could use both the features of robocopy (or xcopy) and the features of 7-zip to verify the copy process.

Comment: Robocopy should already be on your path, so you shouldn't need to specify the path to robocopy.  I think it should look like this:  `Command2 = """Robocopy.exe"" C:\script\files\outzips\ G:\CopyTestFolder\"`

Comment: Hmm...for some reason that is not working. The script runs just fine but it doesn't actually copy to the path. It does work in the command line though so I know that the command is correct. I tried adding in a space like & " " & in between the paths but that just gave me and expected end of statement error =/